# Removing rows from pandas time series where there are stationary intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some dataframes that contain intervals where the values are close to stationary. How could I delete these intervals on the condition that over x amount of samples if the values are constant (or with a given deviation) that particular interval of row values will be deleted from the column?
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZW1F.jpg)
I am using python and pandas

I tried looping over the rows and checking if the values stayed the same, and put those indexes into an interval, did not turn out great. Also, I dont know how to take into account some small deviations from the stationary value

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.diff` to compare successive values and remove rows where the change is below a threshold. See code below (df1) but this won't deal well with sequences of almost-constant values as the total change climbs above the threshold. So a comparison function can be used to form a mask to delete rows by using `.map` over the values. For example see code (df2) below. Note that 1.304 is then retained because of the difference from 1.3 even though it is close to the immediately previous value. You could fairly simply modify this approach to **count** the number of below threshold changes and use that as the criteria. Deleting the rows in these ways will remove near constant data but obviously won't make any difference to your sample plot using the same X-axis.

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame({'val': [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.301, 1.302, 1.303, 1.304, 1.305, 1.4, 1.5]})

threshold = 0.003

mask = df['val'].diff().ge(threshold)
mask[0] = True
df1= df[mask].reset_index(drop = True)
print(df1)
```

gives:

```
   val
0  1.1
1  1.2
2  1.3
3  1.4
4  1.5
```

then the second more refined approach

```
val = None
def func(row):
    global val
    if val is None:
        val = row
        return True
    elif abs(row - val) < threshold:
            return False
    else:
        val = row
        return True

df2 = df[df['val'].map(func)].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df2)
```

gives:

```
     val
0  1.100
1  1.200
2  1.300
3  1.304
4  1.400
5  1.500
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is exactly what you're looking for, but it will remove rows from your pandas dataframe based on a threshold you define for the 'flatness' of a line.
If you've any questions, feel free to ask!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


#Creating mock dataset
x_values = range(20)
y_values = [0,3,4,5,6,8,9,14,20,26,32,40,64,80,85,89,93,96,97,99]

#Converting to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': x_values,
     'y': y_values
    })

#Define a flucutuation threshold that describes anything under as a 'flat' line
acceptable_fluctuation_dif = 2 

indexes_for_deletion = [] #Indexes that are considered 'flat'
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    if index > 0: #Check everything after the first value

        #Check if difference between value and previous value is within defined threshold
        if (abs(row[1]) - abs(df['y'][index-1])) < acceptable_fluctuation_dif: 
            indexes_for_deletion.append(index) #Append to list for later deletion

#Delete 'flat' values from old dataframe to create new one
df2 = df.drop(index=indexes_for_deletion)

#Check before and after plots to see difference reflected
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(x_values,y_values)

df2.plot(x='x', y='y', kind='scatter')
```

Comment: This compares successive values which may not be suitable for all sequences (gradual change); hence my answer. Rather than looping with iterrows the pandas `.diff` compares successive elements directly.

Comment: I get you, my solution won't solve for all scenarios, if like you said, change is quite gradual. I only saw your answer after the page refreshed when I posted this.